# Integer vs. String Issue using Heroku Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error from a recent change I made using heroku console.

After I apply this:

```
u = User.where(:email => 'brian@lumeo.com').first
u.invitation_limit = 10
u.save
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (comparison of String with 0 failed):
```

On this line of code:

```
<% if current_user.invitation_limit > 0 %>
```

invitation_limit is an integer field in the database and the number
10 is clearly an integer, but do I need to use to_i,
like this?

```
u.invitation_limit = 10.to_i
```

Curious if this is a common thing that I am unaware of.

Please let me know if you know anything about this.

Thanks in advance, Brian

Comment: Hi Brian! In the db/schema.rb for User, is the invitation_limit set as a string or an integer?

Comment: Hey Jesse. It's set as an integer.

Comment: I too would like to know more about the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that when you pull the data out of the database, rails is returning everything as a string value - are you using JSON format? Cause that would read as string values.

I would use this:

```
<% if current_user.invitation_limit.to_i > 0 %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Krista. That will probably work to resolve the problem, but it doesn't address the root cause, which is something I'd like to know more about. Interestingly, when the integer is set by a method through a before_save on user, the error does not happen. It's only after I used the console that the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the following magic command in console: `heroku restart` and hit 'Enter'.

works like a charm every time when you getting very very weird errors in your logs.

Nowadays `Heroku` for me is like a an old version of `Windows` - any problem? just restart it!

Comment: That's too true! If in doubt, restart.